# android is not running on my ububtu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

please any one help me for running android 1. version on ubuntu system, my laptop have 4GB RAM when I try to run any simple program of android it gives me ERR: your RAM is not supporting release some memory.
So my question is how do I release this RAM for this application to run
Thank you.

Comment: Hello and welcome to askubuntu. Please reformulate your question. "Running android on 1. version on Ubuntu system" does not make any sense...This https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask might help.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are using android emulator which have less RAM size so that it showing this error. you should make new android emulator and during creating android emulator specify the RAM size means 512 MB and create it . it will work , its works me.